# Custom Capabilities On Custom Post Type not Working

Tags: wordpress

I'm using WordPress with the Church Theme Content plugin, this plugin registers various custom post types and additional taxonomies that specially written themes can take advantage of.

To aide in administrating the site I wanted to modify the capabilities on one of the taxonomies and post types and allow certain users limited permissions on them.  After digging around on here and other sites, I made a simple plugin that modified the capabilities and used the Members plugin to modify the permissions for the user, but since the update to 4.6 it's no longer working and they don't appear in the list of custom capabilities in the Members plugin nor User Role Editor....

I have no idea where to start looking for a solution, I've gone back and forth trying different things and trying to find decent documentation on how it all works but I've got my head in a muddle, any help here would be appreciated.

Current code, was working, now not:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Church Theme Content - Custom Sermon Caps
Description: Allows fine grained control over Sermon Posts
Version:     1
Author:      Tom Wild
Text Domain: ctcCustom-toolset
*/
// Prevent direct access to this file.
if (!defined( 'ABSPATH' )){
    header( 'HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden' );
    echo 'This file should not be accessed directly!';
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

function ctc__modify_caps() {
    // get the arguments of the already-registered taxonomy
    $speaker_category_args = get_taxonomy('ctc_sermon_speaker'); // returns an object

// make changes to the args
$speaker_category_args->capabilities = array(
        'manage_terms' => 'add_speakers',
        'edit_terms'   => 'edit_speakers',
        'delete_terms' => 'delete_speakes',
        'assign_terms' => 'assign_speakers'
        );

$sermon_post_type = get_post_type_object('ctc_sermon');
$sermon_post_type->capability_type = 'sermon';
$sermon_post_type->map_meta_cap = true;
$sermon_post_type->capabilities = array(
        // meta caps (don't assign these to roles)
        'edit_post'              => 'edit_sermon',
        'read_post'              => 'read_sermon',
        'delete_post'            => 'delete_sermon',

        // primitive/meta caps
        'create_posts'           => 'create_sermons',

         // primitive caps used outside of map_meta_cap()
        'edit_posts'             => 'edit_sermons',
        'edit_others_posts'      => 'edit_others_sermons',
        'publish_posts'          => 'publish_sermons',
        'read_private_posts'     => 'read',

        // primitive caps used inside of map_meta_cap()
        'read'                   => 'read',
        'delete_posts'           => 'delete_sermons',
        'delete_private_posts'   => 'delete_private_sermons',
        'delete_published_posts' => 'delete_published_sermons',
        'delete_others_posts'    => 'delete_others_sermons',
        'edit_private_posts'     => 'edit_private_sermons',
        'edit_published_posts'   => 'edit_published_sermons'
        );

// re-register the taxonomy

register_taxonomy('ctc_sermon_speaker', 'ctc_sermon', (array) $speaker_category_args );

    register_post_type('ctc_sermon',(array) $sermon_post_type);
}
add_action('init', 'ctc__modify_caps', 11);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it stopped working, but I found a solution.

After digging through the code for Church Theme Content I found it allowed filters on its registering of post types and taxonomies so I re-wrote my code to:

```
    <?php
    //Other Stuff
    function ctc__do_sermon_tag_filter($args) {
        $args['capabilities'] =  array(
                'manage_terms' => 'add_sermon_tags',
                'edit_terms'   => 'edit_sermon_tags',
                'delete_terms' => 'delete_sermon_tags',
                'assign_terms' => 'assign_sermon_tags'
                );
    }
    function ctc__do_sermon_post_type_filter($args){
       $args['capability_type'] = 'sermon';
       $args['capabilities'] = array(
                // meta caps (don't assign these to roles)
                'edit_post'              => 'edit_sermon',
                'read_post'              => 'read_sermon',
                'delete_post'            => 'delete_sermon',

                // primitive/meta caps
                'create_posts'           => 'create_sermons',

                 // primitive caps used outside of map_meta_cap()
                'edit_posts'             => 'edit_sermons',
                'edit_others_posts'      => 'edit_others_sermons',
                'publish_posts'          => 'publish_sermons',
                'read_private_posts'     => 'read_private_sermons',

                // primitive caps used inside of map_meta_cap()
                'read'                   => 'read',
                'delete_posts'           => 'delete_sermons',
                'delete_private_posts'   => 'delete_private_sermons',
                'delete_published_posts' => 'delete_published_sermons',
                'delete_others_posts'    => 'delete_others_sermons',
                'edit_private_posts'     => 'edit_private_sermons',
                'edit_published_posts'   => 'edit_published_sermons'
                );
        return $args;
    }
    function ctc__add_filters(){
        add_filter('ctc_post_type_sermon_args','ctc__do_sermon_post_type_filter',11);
        add_filter('ctc_taxonomy_sermon_topic_args','ctc__do_sermon_topic_filter',11);
        add_filter('ctc_taxonomy_sermon_book_args','ctc__do_sermon_book_filter',11);
        add_filter('ctc_taxonomy_sermon_series_args','ctc__do_sermon_series_filter',11);
        add_filter('ctc_taxonomy_sermon_speaker_args','ctc__do_sermon_speaker_filter',11);
        add_filter('ctc_taxonomy_sermon_tag_args','ctc__do_sermon_tag_filter',11);    
    }
    add_action('init', 'ctc__add_filters',9);
    ?>
```